# How to load image into scene from menu items?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I need to load an image into a scene when one of the menu options is clicked. Any push in the right direction would be appreciated. Let me know if any more context is needed.

I have tried loading it using this method, to test a variable, and the scene remains the same upon reload:

```
            var testButton = document.getElementById('box1');

            testButton.onclick = function (sceneEditor) {
            sceneEditor = new Scene(img3, camera);
            alert("!");   //test alert
            window.location.reload();

            };
```

The html dropdown menu:

```
<select id="box1" style="margin-left:120px; margin-bottom:-20px; margin- 
top:-30px; padding-top:0">
<option onclick="" value="1">111</option>
<option onclick="" value="2">222</option>
<option onclick="" value="3">333</option>
<option onclick="" value="4">444</option>
</select>
```

The image variables and example scene;

```
var img1 = 'images/111.jpg';
var img2 = 'images/222.jpg';
var img3 = 'images/333.jpg';
var img4 = 'images/444.jpg';

var sceneEditor = new Scene(img2, camera);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load scene from dropdown box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660845/how-to-load-scene-from-dropdown-box)

Comment: You have a few questions which are basically the same. Better to post one and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is by adding all the images to your page and then hide them until a option is clicked. I have tried doing this very simplified below (I have used random images, but you can just replace them with your own)

```html
    <select id="box1" style="margin-left:120px; margin-bottom:-20px; margin-
    top:-30px; padding-top:0" onchange="changeImg();">
    <option onclick="" value="1">111</option>
    <option onclick="" value="2">222</option>
    <option onclick="" value="3">333</option>
    <option onclick="" value="4">444</option>
  </select>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/TVE_La1_-_Logo_2008.png" alt="google" id="imageOne" style="display: none;">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Logo_TVE-2.svg/1200px-Logo_TVE-2.svg.png" alt="twitter" id="imageTwo" style="display: none;">
  <img src="https://www.johnbrownhardware.co.uk/ekmps/shops/513a47/images/classic-designs-3-black-number-3-digit-pack-5-54617-p.jpg" alt="google" id="imageThree" style="display: none;">
  <img src="https://d9np3dj86nsu2.cloudfront.net/image/ceb24870f9f782a6b45b1de4560758bd" alt="twitter" id="imageFour" style="display: none;">
  <script>
    function changeImg() {
      let a = document.getElementById("box1").selectedIndex;
      if (a == "0") {
          document.getElementById("imageOne").style.display = ""
          document.getElementById("imageTwo").style.display = "none"
          document.getElementById("imageThree").style.display = "none"
          document.getElementById("imageFour").style.display = "none"
      } else if (a == "1") {
        document.getElementById("imageOne").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("imageTwo").style.display = ""
        document.getElementById("imageThree").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("imageFour").style.display = "none"
      } else if (a == "2") {
        document.getElementById("imageOne").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("imageTwo").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("imageThree").style.display = ""
        document.getElementById("imageFour").style.display = "none"
      } else if (a == "3") {
        document.getElementById("imageOne").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("imageTwo").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("imageThree").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("imageFour").style.display = ""
      }

    }
  </script>
```